# How to make a function variable be called like jquery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Plugin:

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.myplugin = function( options ) {  

    var mymethod = function(){
      // I want to be able to access "this" here ('.element')

      return this; 
    };

    return this.each(function() {        
      // $('.element', this).mymethod(); <- how to do this?
    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

I want to call mymethod like this:

`$('.element').mymethod();`

Is this possible?

Basically it needs to keep the chaining so I can further call other functions...

Comment: You could get rid of the wrapping function and simply assign to `jQuery.fn.myplugin` (unless you want to be able to use the `$` alias elsewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, I would highly recommend checking out the jQuery plugin authoring page. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

The best way to call a specific method would be by going

```
$( '#foo' ).myPlugin( 'myMethod' );
```

The way you would achieve something like that would be like this, ( note: all taken from the jQuery plugin authoring site )

```
( function ( $ ) {

    var methods = {
        init : function( options ) {

            // Init function here

        },
        destroy : function( ) {

            // Teardown function here

        }
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin= function( method ) {

if ( methods[method] ) {
  return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
} else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
  return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
} else {
  $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin' );
}    


};

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call it like a jQuery plugin you will have no way around adding it to the jQuery prototype ($.fn). But if you just want to have *this* reference the jQuery element of your selector you can just use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.myplugin = function( options ) {  

    var mymethod = function(){
      // I want to be able to access "this" here ('.element')

      return this; 
    };

    return this.each(function() {        
      mymethod.apply($('.element', this));
    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 2):

Close, you just lose the `this` keyword whenever there's a new `function` keyword. Try saving it first:

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.myplugin = function( options ) {  

    var that = this;

    var mymethod = function(_this, dotElem){
      // I want to be able to access "this" here ('.element')
        that.hide().blah()...

      return this; // this isn't needed as we are going to anyway return `this.each()`
    };

    return this.each(function() {        
        mymethod(this, $('.element' )); <- how to do this?
    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1):

Alter MyMethod so its a direct extension

```
$.fn.mymethod = function() {
   this.hide(); // the .element
   return this; // continue the daisy chain
}

// example usage
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("div").mymethod();
});
```

Updated x2 (had a typo)!

http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/2TWMV/1/

Comment: updated with example. For every $.fn."methodName", its a direct extension to the jQuery methods, any return on new object literals are not part of the jQuery extension.

Comment: Within a jQuery method, `this` refers to the jQuery collection, not the underlying array of elements. So, the dollar signs in `$.fn.mymethod` are unnecessary. In fact, the function's body should simply read `return this.hide()`.

Comment: you are correct, although I didn't want to return the daisy chain `this.hide();` since I'm assuming if the goal is to make an extension, there's a bigger task at hand. Updated

Answer (score 1):

Well, then you'd just do:

```
$.fn.mymethod = function () { ...   return this; }
```

jQuery will automatically pass the element it's called on as `this`.

But it's considered bad practice to add lots of functions this way. That's why most plugins just add one function to `$.fn` and take a string argument for which method to call.

Comment: that's why I want to keep the functions as variables, because I have quite a few..